# JSON iteration based on value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to create a simple display of NBA west leaders in order by seed using the following json file:

```
http://data.nba.com/data/v2014/json/mobile_teams/nba/2014/00_standings.json
```

Right now I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON('http://data.nba.com/data/v2014/json/mobile_teams/nba/2014/00_standings.json',function(info){

    var eastHead = info.sta.co[0].val;
    var divi = info.sta.co[0].di[0].val;

    /*evaluate East*/
    for(i=0;i < divi.length;i++){

        var visTeam ='<li>' + divi + '</li>';
         document.getElementById("eastHead").innerHTML=eastHead;
    }
    var seed = info.sta.co[0].di[0].t[0].see;


                    $.each(menuItems.data, function (i) {
                        var eastSeed ='<li>' + seed + '</li>';
                        console.log(eastSeed)
                        document.getElementById("eastSeed").innerHTML=eastSeed;
                    });//$.each(menuItems.data, function (i) {

});//getJSON

});//ready
```

I'm looking just to list out the leaders in order. So right now we have

> 1. Golden State
>     2. Memphis
>     3. Houston
>     4. Portland
>     5. L.A. Clippers
>     6. Dallas
>     .... and so
>      forth.

This is based off of the "see" value which means seed in the west.

This issue is I'm getting a single value rather than an iteration.

Updated:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON('http://data.nba.com/data/v2014/json/mobile_teams/nba/2014/00_standings.json',function(info){



                    /**************************************************/
                        //Get info above here
                        var westDivision = info.sta.co[1].di;
                        westDivision.forEach(function (subdivision)
                        {
                            subdivision.t.forEach(function (team)
                            {
                                westTeams.push({
                                    city: team.tc,
                                    name: team.tn,
                                    seed: team.see
                                });
                            });
                        });
                        function compare(a,b) {
                          if (a.see < b.see)
                             return -1;
                          if (a.see > b.see)
                            return 1;
                          return 0;
                        }
                        var sorted = westTeams.sort(compare);
                        sorted.forEach(function (el,i)
                        {
                            console.log(i+'. '+el.city+' '+el.name);
                        });
                        /**************************************************/    

});//getJSON

});//ready
```

console output :

1. Portland Trail Blazers
2. Oklahoma City Thunder
3. Denver Nuggets
4. Utah Jazz
5. Minnesota Timberwolves
6. Golden State Warriors
7. Los Angeles Clippers
8. Phoenix Suns
9. Sacramento Kings
10. Los Angeles Lakers
11. Memphis Grizzlies
12. Houston Rockets
13. Dallas Mavericks
14. San Antonio Spurs
15. New Orleans Pelicans

Comment: I'm curious. How do you even retrieve the NBA stats from their server with Ajax? This does not work for me (same-origin policy) and I doubt it does for you. Your code sample certainly doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to iterate with forEach. Rather then having to worry about indexes you can directly reference each item of the array.

Using this code you can put the data you want into an array.

```
//Get info above here
var westTeams = [];
var westDivision = info.sta.co[1].di;

westDivision.forEach(function (subdivision)
{
    subdivision.t.forEach(function (team)
    {
        westTeams.push({
            city: team.tc,
            name: team.tn,
            seed: team.see
        });
    });
});
```

Then you can sort them using `obj.sort`

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.seed < b.seed)
     return -1;
  if (a.seed > b.seed)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
var sorted = westTeams.sort(compare);
```

Finally, you can print them in order.

```
sorted.forEach(function (el,i)
{
    console.log((i+1)+'. '+el.city+' '+el.name);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that response. I'm getting 'westTeams is not defined' though. Not sure what that is referencing now as it is defined above right? I've included the updated script in the original message.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally removed the line defining that variable. It should work now.

Comment: This is awesome @J4G but the seed order is inaccurate. Am I missing something? I've included the output above.

Comment: Portland is actually 0 not 1

Comment: I can't initiate a chat, but can you so we can go over this in depth. Just so I can understand what is happening here? I'm confused as to what you did with the purhs. Also the order is still not correct.

Comment: Apparently I don't have enough rep to do this either.

Comment: You can't join the chat? My link was wrong at first, try the new one.

Comment: It says I need 20 rep.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71449/discussion-between-j4g-and-chris).

Answer (score 1):

Querying a large JavaScript object graph can be a tedious thing, especially if you want to have dynamic output. Implementing support for different filter criteria, sort orders, "top N" restrictions, paging can be difficult. And whatever you come up with tends to be inflexible.

To cover these cases you can (if you don't mind the learning curve) use [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) ([reference](http://neue.cc/reference.htm)), a library that implements .NET's LINQ for JavaScript.

The following showcases what you can do with it. Long post, bear with me.

**Preparation**

Your NBA data object follows a parent-child hierarchy, but it misses a few essential things:

- there are no `parent` references
- the property that contains the children is called differently on every level (i.e. `co`, `di`, `t`)

In order to make the whole thing uniform (and therefore traversable), we first need to build a tree of nodes from it. A tree node would wrap objects from your input graph and would look like this:

```
{
    obj: o,       /* the original object, e.g. sta.co[1]               */
    parent: p,    /* the parent tree node, e.g. the one that wraps sta */
    children: []  /* array of tree nodes built from e.g. sta.co[1].di  */
}
```

The building of this structure can be done recursively in one function:

```
function toNode(obj) {
    var node = {
            obj: obj,
            parent: this === window ? null : this,
            // we're interested in certain child arrays, either of:
            children: obj.co || obj.di || obj.t || []
        };

    // recursive step (with reference to the parent node)
    node.children = node.children.map(toNode, node);

    // (*) explanation below
    node.parents = Enumerable.Return(node.parent)
        .CascadeDepthFirst("$ ? [$.parent] : []").TakeExceptLast(1);

    return node;
}
```

(*) The `node.parents` property is a convenience facility. It contains an enumeration of all parent nodes except the last one (i.e. the root node, which is `null`). This enumeration can be used for filtering as shown below.

The result of this function is a nice-and-uniform interlinked tree of nodes. *(Expand the code snippet, but unfortunately it currently does not run due to same-origin browser restrictions. Maybe there is something in the NBA REST API that needs to be turned on first.)*

```js
function toNode(obj) {
    var node = {
            obj: obj,
            parent: this === window ? null : this,
            children: obj.co || obj.di || obj.t || []
        };
    node.children = node.children.map(toNode, node);
    node.parents = Enumerable.Return(node.parent)
        .CascadeDepthFirst("$ ? [$.parent] : []").TakeExceptLast(1);
    return node;
}

$(function () {
    var standingsUrl = 'http://data.nba.com/data/v2014/json/mobile_teams/nba/2014/00_standings.json';
    $.getJSON(standingsUrl, function(result) {
        var sta = toNode(result.sta);
        console.log(sta);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Result**

Now that we have a fully traversable tree of nodes, we can use LINQ queries to do complex things with only a few lines of code:

```
// first build our enumerable stats tree
var stats = Enumerable.Return(toNode(result.sta));

// then traverse into children; the ones with a tid are teams
var teams = stats.CascadeDepthFirst("$.children")
    .Where("$.obj.tid");
```

OK, we have identified all teams, so we can...

```
// ...select all that have a parent with val 'West' and order them by 'see'
var westernTeams = teams.Where(function (node) {
        return node.parents.Any("$.obj.val === 'West'");
    })
    .OrderByDescending("$.obj.see");

// ...insert the top 5 into our page as list items
westernTeams.Take(5).Do(function (node) {
    $("<li></li>", {text: node.obj.tc + ' ' + node.obj.tn}).appendTo("#topFiveList");
});

// ...turn them as an array of names
var names = westernTeams.Select("$.obj.tc + ' ' + $.obj.tn").ToArray();
console.log(names);
```

Of course what I have done there in several steps could be done in one:

```
// request details for all Northwest and Southeast teams who have won more than one game (*)
var httpRequests = Enumerable.Return(toNode(result.sta))
    .CascadeDepthFirst("$.children")
    .Where("$.obj.tid")
    .Where(function (node) {
        var str = node.obj.str.split(" ");
        return str[0] === "W" && str[1] > 1 && 
            node.parents.Any("$.obj.val==='Northwest' || $.obj.val==='Southeast'");
    })
    .Select(function (node) {
        return $.getJSON(detailsUrl, {tid: node.obj.tid});
    })
    .ToArray();

$.when.apply($, httpRequests).done(function () {
    var results = [].slice.call(arguments);
    // all detail requests have been fetched, do sth. with the results
});
```

(*) correct me if I'm wrong, I have no idea what the data in the JSON file actually means